# Using iPad camera as default in Sidecar

Tags: macbook-pro, ipad, catalina, sidecar

Sidecar works well, but is there is any option to use my iPad camera and speaker as default while using Sidecar.

Catalina V 10.15.3 (19D76)

Answer (score 1):

According to the post [Sidecar iPad Camera](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253762199) on the Apple discussion forums and my own experience, it is not supported.

macOS Ventura + iOS 16 will add support for using your iPhone as a webcam which is, I believe, what you are asking for.